# Netcore 2.2 Localized Routing - How to always redirect to default route

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, localization, asp.net-core-localization

Successfully using the project laid out at [Localized routing using ASP.NET Core MVC 2](https://saaratrix.blogspot.com/2017/12/localized-routing-aspnet-core-mvc-2.html) however there are a few modifications I'd like to make and I'm not clear on how to go about.

Currently my start.cs looks like the below, this works fine however what it does is in the Default culture English, my route is www.site.com whereas when i switch to any other culture I get www.site.com/fr/accuel or www.site.com/es/casa...

How can I get the Default Language to always appear as www.site.com/en/home

startup.cs

```
// Set up cultures
LocalizationRouteDataHandler.DefaultCulture = "en";
LocalizationRouteDataHandler.SupportedCultures = new Dictionary<string, string>()
{
    { "en", "English" },
    { "fr", "Français" },
    { "es", "Español" }
};
```

And my HomeController

```
[AllowAnonymous]
[LocalizationRoute("en", "home")]
[LocalizationRoute("fr", "accueil")]
[LocalizationRoute("es", "casa")]
public class HomeController : LocalizationController
{
    [LocalizationRoute("en", "/home")]
    [LocalizationRoute("fr", "/accueil")]
    [LocalizationRoute("es", "/casa")]
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `LocalizationRoute`, it defines the route template for MVC, which is used to map the request to the action.

For default design, for request `/` which will be routed to `Home/Index` with english culture. If you prefer to show the url with `/en/home` you need to redirect the url by code below:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    var options = new RewriteOptions()
    .AddRedirect(@"^$", $"{LocalizationRouteDataHandler.DefaultCulture}/{LocalizationRouteDataHandler.DefaultController}");           

    app.UseRewriter(options);

    var localizationOptions = app.ApplicationServices.GetService<IOptions<RequestLocalizationOptions>>();
    app.UseRequestLocalization(localizationOptions.Value);            

    //rest code
    app.UseMvc(routes =>
    {
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "default",
            template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}",
            defaults: new { culture = LocalizationRouteDataHandler.DefaultCulture }
        );
    });
}
```

**Note** For above way, you need to keep `[LocalizationRoute("en", "/home")]` to HomeController.